# How is a two-pass assembler designed?

Tags: assembly, algorithm, assembler

What is the algorithm for the *first pass* and the *second pass* of an assembler?

I have been looking for a description or tutorial but haven't found one. If there are tutorials that explain these algorithms, please link them in the answers!

Comment: This is entirely **off topic** here, unless you're looking to build an assembler in hardware. ;) (but briefly: in the first pass you build your symbol table, discovering labels, macros and symbols. In the second pass, you assemble code which references symbols in the symbol table you just built. There are assemblers with more than two passes, and probably single-pass ones too. There are many assembly languages and many assemblers for each, after all)

Comment: This is a good question, but belongs on StackOverflow.

Comment: @ Alexios No not off topic

Comment: this topic is so closely related to hardware. You can't separate it

Comment: Knowing this stuff is a integral part of writing firmware, which is a integral part of electronic design.  The high level computer weenies on the other sites wouldn't know how to spell "assembler".

Comment: @steve - of course you can separate it. You don't have to know beans about electronics to write an assembly program, or an assembler, for that matter. To me it's off topic and I vote to close.

Comment: @stevenvh: We usually consider firmware questions here on topic.  To me this is relavent to firmware.

Comment: @Alexios - It's not entirely off-topic.  We welcome questions about the writing of firmware (which is often in assembly) and the use and configuration of tools here. There's a fuzzy line where it becomes application programming and needs to go on SO, but this isn't definitively on one side of the line or the other.

Comment: @Olin, Kevin - Assembly code may be relevant, but the assembler itself is a program which is written in a high level language (if you're a masochist you *can* write it in assembly) and runs on a PC.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - To counter my last point, there's a wide spectrum of folks in the almost 1,000,000 users on Stack Overflow.  They've got over 4,000 questions about [assembly and assembler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly), but they've unfortunately made them synonyms so there's no way to ask about just the tool.   That's a lot of information about assembly and assembler.  I will admit that it's mostly about x86 and the `as` program.

Comment: @stevenvh - True, but we do support asking questions about tools, and if you need to write your own tool, it makes sense that we'd be able to help with that.  I think that questions about, say, how to make the program accept command line arguments would be a much better fit for Stack Overflow, but questions about the theory behind assemblers seem more relevant.  In any case, I've created a question on Meta where we can talk about this more: [Are questions about writing an assembler on-topic?](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/973/)

Comment: @Alexios: See OP's comment to my answer. You guys were apparently right, this is about the general design of assemblers as apposed to what two-passes means when writing microcontroller code (as I originally interpreted this question). Also the *gimme the algorithm* attitude feels like rather a slap in the face after I spent the time trying to help this guy. I'm with you folks now. Sorry it took so long.

Comment: I think some of the details surrounding some assemblers workings would probably be relevant here. However I'm voting to close this one as it seems the OP only wants "the algorithm", which is probably too broad a subject to deal with entirely here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different assemblers do things differently, so there is no one answer.  Some assemblers are only single pass, for example.

Assemblers that are two-pass generally do the memory allocation and thereby fix locations in the first pass.  These values are then treated like constants on the second pass where the opcodes are generated.

Two passes allows, for example, putting a table at the bottom of the module, having the assembler automatically compute the size of the table, and then use that size value as a constant in code higher up in the module.  I'll use Microchip MPASM for a PIC 16 in a example since this is a two-pass assembler.  (By the way, the ASM30 assembler for the dsPIC series is one-pass, and suffers from limitations as a result).  Consider this code:

```
         movlw   table_size  ;get number of entries in list

         ...

table
         dw      11          ;list of favorite values
         dw      13
         dw      17
         dw      19
table_size equ   $ - table   ;number of list entries
```

The $-table computation is performed in the first pass and the value of TABLE_SIZE set accordingly.  This is then used in the second pass when the MOVLW instruction is generated.  This sort of thing is not possible with a one-pass assembler like ASM30.

Comment: I wanted the algorithm for pass 1 assembler and pass 2 assembler

Comment: @steve: Then go look it up in a computer science text.  I thought you wanted to understand the passes from a usage point of view.  Apparently this really is off topic here.